# Boost runtime error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        using namespace boost::asio;
        io_service iosev;
        ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(iosev, 
        ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 1000));
        for(;;)
        {
                ip::tcp::socket socket(iosev);
                acceptor.accept(socket);
                std::cout << socket.remote_endpoint().address() << std::endl;
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                socket.write_some(buffer("hello world!"), ec);
                if(ec)
                {
                        std::cout << 
                                boost::system::system_error(ec).what() << std::endl;
                        break;
                }

        }
        return 0;
}
```

compiled using command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lboost_system
```

It complied without any errors.
But when i try to run it,it gives me this.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

running on Mac 10.8.Trying to figure out why.

Comment: exception may be thrown somewhere, try to use `try catch` blocks to wrap your code up properly

Answer (score 1):

According to the Asio documentation, the following functions you use may throw exception [ip::tcp::acceptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload3.html), [accept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/accept/overload3.html). However, almost every throwing function in Asio has a non-throwing counterpart that returns an `error_code`. So, either `catch` exceptions or use the non-throwing versions.